# Is it more efficient to run torrents sequentially or in parallel, if they share many of their peers?

Tags: networking, bittorrent

A group of torrents share >90% of their swarms. (They have the same seeds/peers)

Is it faster/more efficient to sequentially download them to avoid peer's bandwidth/queue contention? Or parallel is still the best way?

Note: I think torrent clients may limit seeding connections to one for IP, and don't share "share ratio credits" between separates torrents, but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are too many variables to be sure in a live environment. Load on the seeder side probably isnt constant.

Add them all together and allow your client to pull as much as it can, in a well seeded swarm the total upstream will be far greater than your downstream so you'll get the throughput you can.